# Number of requests in Asp.NET Web Api post method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await, asp.net-web-api

Can a post-method in Asp.NET Web Api process 25000 or 30000 requests in 1 second?

It is a good idea use Async Await?

Comment: Are these requests all coming from different clients? Do they depend on session state? Are you cookie-free? Are the responses cacheable? Do you have asynchronous work to do? Have you done load testing? Is your service scale-outable?

Comment: We have a test client, it sends 1000 request per second. We run our testclient 20 times from differents instances. In the server we want save the text sent through sql executenonqueryasync

Comment: I would say async/await is a good thing to do in order to free the IIS threads, but only worth it if the process of each request takes some meaningful time. As @StephenCleary says, load testing is the only thing that will give you an answer

Comment: @AlejandroMosquera: If you're writing to a single SQL Server backend, your bottleneck will almost certainly be the SQL Server, not ASP.NET.